# NaN with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `my_df` in which one column `my_col` has `NaN` values. I would like to replace `NaN` values with `0`. Doing

```
my_df.my_col = my_df.my_col.fillna(0)
```

returns the following error:

> 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: The solution provided in this link is not adapted to my problem.

Comment: @johndoe43567 I am not sure what you mean. The linked solution is exactly what you need: `mydf = mydf.fillna(0, subset=['my_col'])`